# Google SignIn + Facebook

Tags: swift, swift2, facebook-login, google-signin, appdelegate

I have a problem with the Swift 2 code, the problem is as follows:

I implemented login with Facebook and Google but the two features in app separately in its AppDelegate do not want someone can help me make them working?

I tried different code with poor results, only work one at a time.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation))
    {
        return true
    }
    else if (FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation))
    {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```